# ampscript content if I set to List and not DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In the ampscript content if I set to List and not DE like this “set @Program =v(ProgramOfInterests)” and preview test with a list. this will bring up content data related to the correct program.

If I change this to “set @Program =v(Lead:Global_Program_of_Interest_1__c) ” and use the DE “Leads from High School Visits ”

It does not work and this is where I need

I've added the email template code below and this is my Data Extension that is created by my Journey "Leads from High School Visits":

```
Lead:Campaign_Event_Type

__cLead:High_School_Name

__cLead:FirstName

Lead:LastName

Lead:Global_School_Program_of_Interest_1
__cLead:Global_Program_of_Interest_1__c High School/College Visit St. Michael Catholic Secondary SchoolTest 1 RobertwynterSchool of Media, Art & DesignBroadcasting - Radio & Contemporary Media
```

AMPScript

```
%%[ var @Program,@url, @ColumnCredential2, @ColumnSemester2, @ColumnProgramCode, @ColumnSchool, @ColumnLeft, @ColumnRight, @ColumnCredential, @ColumnSemester, @ColumnLocation, @ColumnTitleDescription, @ColumnDescription, @ColumnHeaderPic, @ColumnMiddlePic, @ColumnBotPic, @ColumnQuote, @ColumnQuoteFrom, @ColumnQuoteFromPosition

    set @Program =v(Lead:Global_School_Program_of_Interest_1__c)
    set @ColumnProgramCode = Lookup("Program_Interest", "ProgramCode", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @url = Concat("http://www.durhamcollege.ca/",@ColumnProgramCode)
    set @ColumnSchool = Lookup("Program_Interest", "SchoolProgram", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnCredential= Lookup("Program_Interest", "CredentialAwarded", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnSemester = Lookup("Program_Interest", "NumberOfSemesters", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnCredential2= Lookup("Program_Interest", "CredentialAwarded2", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnSemester2 = Lookup("Program_Interest", "NumberOfSemester2", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnLocation= Lookup("Program_Interest", "CampusLocation", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnTitleDescription = Lookup("Program_Interest", "TitleDescription", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnDescription = Lookup("Program_Interest", "Description", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnHeaderPic= Lookup("Program_Interest", "HeaderImage", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnMiddlePic = Lookup("Program_Interest", "MiddleImage", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnBotPic = Lookup("Program_Interest", "BottomImage", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnProgramCode = Lookup("Program_Interest", "ProgramCode", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnQuote = Lookup("Program_Interest", "Quote", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnQuoteFrom = Lookup("Program_Interest", "QuoteFrom", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnQuoteFromPosition = Lookup("Program_Interest", "QuoteFromDescription", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnLeft = Lookup("Program_Interest", "LeftSideHTML", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    set @ColumnRight = Lookup("Program_Interest", "RightSideHTML", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)
    ]%%

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px" width="100%">
        2
         /tr></table>
```

Comment: You've switched to DEs and fields with spaces and colons in their names. Have you tried encapsulating their names with []? Also look at AttributeValue() to retrieve what you want from the DE.

Comment: OMG. I could hug you right now. I've been emailing support back and forth for 3 days and everything he suggested didn't work. You look at it, for what a few minutes? The [ ] was the key. the only issue I have now is that it's not producing the correct font and color. thanks again Andrew. My stress level just went down a few notches

Comment: Happy to hear, Robert. I've certainly been in your boots. Marketing Cloud's a frustrating thing. But pretty liberating, too. There's not so much you can't do (with a little creativity). Be creative.

Answer (score 0):

Where the field you want to refer to in your AMPScript contains non-Alphanumeric characters or spaces, encapsulate the field name in square brackets "[my: field]" or initiate an AMPScript variable using AttributeVale("my: field").